# Resample a large image with PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, imagemagick

I'm trying to resample an image by calling the ImageMagick resampleImage method, but when I do that it fails on high CPU load which breaks all my server (including nginx)...

```
$src->resampleImage(320,320,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);
```

Server doesn't have a videocard and the power is limited to the t2.small instance of AWS (which is 1 CPU and 2GB of memory).

I've tried replacing that with setImageResolution method or trying to set the memory limits, but I didn't got anywhere. Server is too loaded which kills my nginx and the whole image is not processed at all.

Also it worth mentioning that I run the resampling throught the CRON task from command line, my server OS is Ubuntu and ImageMagick version is 7.

**Update: We've identified that the version which is used in convert and in php are different. Do you know how PHP knows which ImageMagick version is used?**

convert -version returns 7.0
php iMagick module getVerion returns 6.8.9

Thanks!

Comment: What's the image size?

Comment: is that only for a specific image?

Comment: It happens for all images, most of them are 5000*5000 and more.

Comment: Update: We've identified that the version which is used in convert and in php are different. Do you know how PHP knows which ImageMagick version is used?

Comment: Does your input image have both a density and units specified? Sometimes an image has no units and/or the density is set or interpreted as 1.

Comment: @fmw42 It happens on all images, including the one that has resolution set in properties.

Comment: It is possible your server is set to limit the amount of resources. Also ImageMagick has policy.xml file that allow you to set resources for imagemagick. You can see what is current using convert -list resource. Perhaps you need to modify your policy.xml file or check with your server IT about any limitations they have set.

Comment: @fmw Not likely, as I mentioned I was able to resample the image from command-line, but when I do that from iMagick php extension it has massive CPU consumption and stops the whole server...

I found that versions in PHP extensions and ImageMagick in command line are different. How PHP extension knows which version to run?

Comment: I am not an expert on Imagick and do not know how it knows what version to run. Presumably it is set in some PHP environment variable. Did you look in the phpinfo.php file? Or perhaps Imagick uses whatever version is in its same path.

Comment: I have the same problem, MORE RAM did the trick for me :-) - are you sure it crashes? Mostly IM takes very long because of to less memory and your browser get a timeout...after a while you should be able to access the page again and IM has done the job. - another idear is to switch to graphicsmagic, maybe this takes less resources, but I did not evaluated that jet.

Comment: @TobiasGaertner Thanks, I've already upgraded the server from t2.micro to t2.small, don't want to bother the client by upgrading the server from t2.small to t2.medium, especially that in command line operation happens pretty fast...

Probably it's something very specific to the version of IM i'm running...

Comment: I finally removed the resampleImage function from my process - my aim was just to resize the image and the final result has no significant difference without. Now its running very fast :-)

Comment: @TobiasGaertner Unfortunately for me I need to use it as the app is used commercial printing hardware which has requirements for image sampling.... :(

Comment: So I think the only way afaik is to provide hardware that can handle operations like this. Its not always only the memory-size, could be video-card or chipset too. New INTEL Platforms has sometimes special chips for handling stuff like video-encoding and so - maybe this whould be a way to go. Otherwise maybe to switch into an other lib like graphicsMagick cauld be a way, but never tryed myself.